# Flexslider does not Pause when last slide is reached

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Currently, I have multiple slides in one Flexslider view. The moment I reach the last view of Flexslider slides, it bounces back to the first slide once I touch it to turn the page to the next view. Is there anyway to pause it, instead of sliding back? I just wanted to have the user to have more control rather than suddenly moving back.

Here's my setting for Flexslider:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation:  "slide",
        animationLoop: true,
        itemWidth: 20,
        minItems: 1,
        maxItems: 2.5,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        touch: true,
        reverse: false,
        easing: false,
    });
  });
```

Comment: `animationLoop: true`

Answer (score 0):

Add 'after',it should work

```
after: function (slider) {
    if (slider.currentSlide == 0) {
         slider.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: It still bounces and turns to the page the first group of views.